# How to Setup an Authenticated S3 REST Endpoint for Public PUT Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to setup an S3 bucket that faces the public internet so that an external process can make `PUT` requests to upload data to the bucket.

I am trying to limit access so that only signed requests are able to be authenticated.  I found [instructions in the developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) on creating the signature in the external process but I can't find instructions on how to setup the S3 bucket.

**What are the necessary steps to setup an S3 bucket, with customer managed encryption keys, to allow only authenticated PUT REST requests?**

As I understand it: I need to create a user with a role that can access the KMS key & S3 bucket.  But I can't find instructions on the S3 bucket setup.  I'm looking for specifics related to public access settings, ACLs, etc.

Note: the external process cannot use an AWS SDK, only standard REST requests (e.g. `curl`).

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: You appear to be describing how an S3 bucket works, by default.  They are accessible from the Internet but they only allow authenticated access from IAM users and/or roles with the appropriate permissions. "Public access" in S3 parlance means "unauthenticated access," not Internet connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want a combination of S3, API Gateway and Lambda:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

The API Gateway can be leveraged for securing access based on the client certificate:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-setup-ssl-certificate.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  However, the link that I provided in the question indicates that the functionality I'm looking for is directly available from S3 without additional services.  I'm hoping for a "pure" S3 solution...